# .Net - Share token between two webapi on same IIS

Tags: .net, asp.net-web-api2, bearer-token

I have a project based on Angular2 for FrontEnd and a .Net WebApi 2.0 for the backend.

Now I have to implement a parallel project that has to use the same Authentication.

What I want to do in my mind is create a new webapi 2.0 and share the token between the two webapi in order to avoid the user to provide the same user and password if he switch between projects.

Is it possible ?

The other solution is use the same Webapi for project2 and extend the controllers/methods, but I want to create a new project for it.

Thanks to support

Answer (score 1):

If the JWT signing key is the same on both API's and you turn off validate Issuer, the token will work on both API's.

Example

```
services.AddAuthentication(JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme)
             .AddJwtBearer(options =>
             {
                 options.TokenValidationParameters = new TokenValidationParameters
                 {
                     ValidateIssuer = false, //this needs to be false 
                     ValidateLifetime = true,
                     ValidateIssuerSigningKey = true,
                     ClockSkew = TimeSpan.Zero,
                     IssuerSigningKey = new SymmetricSecurityKey(Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes("fjboJU3s7rw2Oafzum5fBxZoZ5jihQRbpBZcxZFd/gY="))

                 };
             });
```

Create some claims (roles are just a list of strings)

```
public List<Claim> CreateJwtClaims( String UserId, List<String> Roles) 
    {
        // create a list of claims and add userId 
        var Claims = new List<Claim>
        {
            new Claim(ClaimTypes.Name, UserId)
        };
        // add roles to the claims list
        // for every role add a new claim type role
        foreach (var role in Roles)
        {
            Claims.Add(new Claim(ClaimTypes.Role, role));
        }

       return Claims;
    }
```

create a token passing claims

```
 public string CreateToken(List<Claim> Claims)
    {
        // JWT Key must be the same as in startup 

        string JwtSigningKey = "fjboJU3s7rw2Oafzum5fBxZoZ5jihQRbpBZcxZFd/gY=";

        // create a security key
        var Key = new SymmetricSecurityKey(System.Text.Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(JwtSigningKey));

        // sign the key using specified algorithm
        var Creds = new SigningCredentials(Key, SecurityAlgorithms.HmacSha256);

        // create the token from the signed credentials
        var Token = new JwtSecurityToken(
          issuer: "localhost", // or try setting issues the the same from both
          audience: "localhost",
          claims:Claims // passed claims
          expires: DateTime.Now.AddMinutes(10), //expires in 10 mins
          signingCredentials: Creds);


        return new JwtSecurityTokenHandler().WriteToken(Token);
    }
```

in your controller add authorize

```
[Authorize] // this says you must have a valid token
// [Authorize(Roles = "admin")]  and must be in role admin created in claims 
[Route("api/[controller]")]
public class ValuesController : Controller
```

Answer (score 0):

Well, if application is hosted in 2 different environment it will be treated as 2 different applications, however Load Balancer was introduced to handle multiple environments.

With respect to .net :
Out Proc session is the one you should be looking for, both the web application need a common layer to save token, it can be DB, Shared File, etc., but has to be common layer.

Other approach I can go with to generate a Same token everytime when particular set of parameter is passed to it

With both approach, you have to make a 1 common layer.

Comment: The environment is the same, also the domain is the same... Its just 2 similar application on the same IIS... What about to manage the MachineKey in webconfig ?

Comment: You mentioned Same User and Password, so if 1 user comes in you will navigate to either of the hosted application, that what I said a common layer that can be any algo, DB, file, even a different web service where you can send userid password and generate a token

Comment: I already have a database where I implement .net Identity, I just have to share token between the apps